# explain: For all integers $a$ and $b$, if $a$ and $b$ are positive and $a$ divides $b$, then $a ≤ b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

In my college textbook they explain the following theorem, but I couldn't understand the reasoning behind some sections of the proof:

> Proof:
> Suppose $a$ and $b$ are positive integers and $a$ divides $b$. [We must show that $a ≤ b$.]
> Then there exists an integer $k$ so that $b = ak$. Because both $a$ and $b$ are positive, $k$
> must be positive. so, it follows that
> $1 ≤ k$
> because every positive integer is greater than or equal to $1$. Multiplying both sides
> by a gives
> $a ≤ ka = b$
> because multiplying both sides of an inequality by a positive number preserves the
> inequality. Thus a ≤ b [as was to be shown].

---

My problem is this part:

> Because both $a$ and $b$ are positive, $k$ must be positive. so, it follows that
> $1 ≤ k$

I don't get how $1 ≤ k$ follows from $a$, $b$, and $k$ being positive. Also, why use $1 ≤ k$ in the proof when you would think to use $b = ak$?

Comment: $1$ is the smallest possible positive integer.

Comment: It is explained in the text you quoted: "*because every positive integer is greater than or equal to $1$*".

Comment: @dxiv I understand this part. My problem is why does it matter for the proof. i doesn't seem intuitive to me. why not use $b=ak$ instead of $1≤k$?

Comment: @Omar: The proof does use $b=ak$, in a rather essential way: it's what gets us from $a\le ka$ to $a\le b$.

Comment: @Omar Not sure I follow. The proof uses *both* $1 \le k$ *and* $a = kb$ on the very next line.

Comment: i mean why can't we prove from b=ak directly by substitution.

Comment: i just noticed my mistake. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flow of implications is
$$
\text{$a$ and $b$ are positive integers}\implies\text{$k$ is a positive integer}\implies\text{$1\le k$}
$$
The first implication holds for the following reason: we know that $b=ak$, and that both $a$ and $b$ are positive; if $k$ were negative, then $b$ would be the product of a positive and a negative integer, and so $b$ would be negative; this is a contradiction. Therefore, $k$ must be positive or zero. If $k=0$, then $b=a\times 0=0$, which again is a contradiction. This means that $k$ must be positive.

The second implication holds for the reason stated in the text: a positive integer is, by definition, an integer greater than $0$. This means that the positive integers are the numbers $1,2,3,4,5$, etc. All of these integers are greater than or equal to $1$. Therefore, since $k$ is a positive integer, it must be a greater than or equal to $1$.

You also ask

> Why use $1 ≤ k$ in the proof when you would think to use $b = ak$?

Actually, both $1\le k$ and $b=ak$ are used in the proof. Since $1\le k$ and $a$ is positive, it follows that $a\le ak$. Therefore, since $b=ak$, this means that $a\le b$.

Indeed, since "$a$ divides $b$" *means* that there exists an integer $k$ such that $b=ak$, the fact that $b=ak$ is a hypothesis of the theorem you quote. In almost all theorems you encounter, you will need to use every hypothesis to prove the statement. If one of the hypotheses weren't necessary, then why include it in the statement of the theorem?

Comment: ok thanks for the help. i have another question: why can't the proof be solved by removing $1≤k$ and start from $b=ak$ through substituting $k$ with $1$.
 ,

Comment: @Omar: No problem. Regarding your follow-up question, we are not allowed to simply substitute $k=1$. We are told that $a$ divides $b$, so that *there exists* an integer $k$ such that $b=ak$. But we are not told what $k$ is, and so we can't simply assume $k=1$. Think of an example: if $a=5$ and $b=20$, then $a$ and $b$ are positive integers and $a$ divides $b$, but it is not the case that $k=1$ (in this example, $k=4$). Does that help?

Comment: ok my bad I just noticed that it says 1≤k. oops! thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define $k$ as positive integer, because if it were negative or $0$ $(k\le 0)$, you'd have $b=ak\le0$, and since $a>0$, that would imply $b\le 0$, which is an obvious contradiction. As for why $1\le k$, as it was already stated in the comments by AnCar and dxiv, simply because $1$ is the smallest possible positive integer and $k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$.